# Open source projects for GIS

Tags: open-source, gis, geoserver

I work with GIS and want to find a good open source project to edit and publish geospatial data. I  googled and found Geoserver.It is a very good project but it has GPL license. Are there other open source projects for gis?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: There's a whole echo system of open source GIS software and tools. a good place to start would be: [The Open Source Geospatial Foundation](https://www.osgeo.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use web based open source GIS, try [**OpenGeo Suite**](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/)

Also there are several libraries for GIS, like [**GeoTools**](http://www.geotools.org/) and [**DotSpatial**](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/).

Finally, you can see [**this**](http://opensourcegis.org/) for complete index of Open Source / Free GIS related software projects.